Fetch a page content from wordpress admin panel
I've a "Callback requests" page in my wordpress admin panel that is show below.
enter image description here
I want to fetch this page contents with request module and then fetch the "Name" and "Phone" element with BeautifulSoup module. Since this page is in admin panel it requires username and password.
I would be pleased if someone can help me to fetch page's contents.
import requests

URL = "https://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ar-contactus-key-requests&paged=1"
AUTH = ("username", "password")
RESPONSE = requests.get(url, auth=AUTH)

Unfortunately the 'RESPONSE' contains the wordpress admin login page's data not the actual data that is in 'URL'.

Of course you get the login page, because you are not logged in. auth=AUTH is HTTP Authentication - not what WordPress uses.

first, you need to send a POST request for login. then you read the cookie in the answer and use the cookie for the GET request.

Here is my code:
import requests
payload = {'action': 'login', 'user_login': 'username', 'user_pass': 'password'}
url = 'https://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php'
session = requests.Session()
response = session.post(url, data=payload)
How can I check if the login is success? How can I get the cookie back and use it for the future get request?
Thanks @Kaperto

In order to access the data you need to authenticate (as the admin), but you're sending the credentials via auth header, which isn't designed for such a purpose.
What you need to do is to manually log in as the admin and, tipically, get a session cookie.
With this authentication token, which will probably be stored as a cookie so read something about requests.sessions.Session, you can access the content of the page.

Thank you for consideration my problem.
Since I'm very new on this subject, I would be pleased if some can walk me through step by step

Is there a POST request which can be used in order to log in? You must know that first, send that request, the server response will contain a cookie which you will send along with your GET request in order to access the asked resource.
